# Why was the piranhadon scene deleted from Peter Jackson’s King Kong?

Tags: king-kong-2005

In *King Kong* (the Peter Jackson version), why was the piranhadon scene deleted?

Was it because the movie was already 188 minutes? Or was King-Kong too far to have a "versus" battle? (King Kong would win I guess ^^) Also a triceratops scene exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could find is that it was most likely cut due to the [already long running time of the movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0360717/trivia?item=tr0777537).

The scene can be found in the extended version, available on home video.

Comment: I just watched the extended cut of the movie, its there and I have to concur with this answer and in the running time allotted for this movie I have to assume they would have liked to have more scenes with king kong on it and the piranhadon scene doesn't have king kong on it.